# call ejb remote interface from another ejb module

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I can't inject a remote ejb from another ejb module. I have the application split into a library and two ejb modules. I try to access from a ejb module to another module through a remote interface and get javax.naming.NameNotFoundException.
I try to access from NewBean "@EJB private CountryFacadeRemote". I used glassfish.
I have to configure something? Thanks.

[Download SourceCode](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80642164/QuestionWeb/MyAppTestEJB.zip)

**MyAppTestEJBDomainLibrary:**

*Country:

```
public class Country implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
...

}
```

*CountryFacadeRemote:

```
@Remote
public interface CountryFacadeRemote {

void create(Country country);
void edit(Country country);
void remove(Country country);
Country find(Object id);
List<Country> findAll();
List<Country> findRange(int[] range);
int count();

}
```

**MyAppTestEJB: (ejb module)**

*AbstractFacade:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();
...

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
}
```

*CountryFacade:

```
@Stateless
public class CountryFacade extends AbstractFacade<Country> implements CountryFacadeLocal, CountryFacadeRemote {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public CountryFacade() {
    super(Country.class);
}
}
```

**MyAppTestEJBOther: (ejb module)**

*NewBean:

```
@Singleton
public class NewBean {

@EJB
private CountryFacadeRemote countryFacade;

@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*")
public void businessMethod() {
    System.out.println("NumCountries:" + countryFacade.count());
}
}
```

**ERROR OUTPUT:**

```
WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB NewBean, method: public void net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean.businessMethod()
WARNING:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton NewBean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:396)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.checkInit(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:368)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer._getContext(CMCSingletonContainer.java:116)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3990)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1199)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:89)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1919)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton NewBean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:483)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:81)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:654)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade,Remote 3.x interface =net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,refType=Session into class net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:443)
... 19 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade,Remote 3.x interface =net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,refType=Session into class net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
... 25 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade,Remote 3.x interface =net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote not found]]]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
... 28 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean/countryFacade,Remote 3.x interface =net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote not found]]
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
... 32 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote not found]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
... 37 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote#net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote not found
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
... 41 more

WARNING:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB NewBean, method: public void net.myapp.myapptestejbother.NewBean.businessMethod()
WARNING:   javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton NewBean is unavailable because its original initialization failed.
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.checkInit(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:359)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer._getContext(CMCSingletonContainer.java:116)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:3990)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1199)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$000(EJBTimerService.java:89)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:1919)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved adding `lookup` to EJB annotation:

`@EJB(lookup = "java:global/MyAppTestEJB/CountryFacade!net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote")`

```
@Singleton
public class NewBean {

    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/MyAppTestEJB/CountryFacade!net.myapp.ejb.CountryFacadeRemote")
    private CountryFacadeRemote countryFacade;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*")
    public void businessMethod() {
        System.out.println("NumCountries:" + countryFacade.count());
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?